# How to close a window in multi-window mode?

Tags: multi-window

How do I close a window in multi-window mode? I know I can show/hide the Windows supporting multi-window by keeping the Back key pressed/held down. Once I drag an app out of the multi-window and then another one how do I close it.

I am also slightly surprised that only few apps use multi-window.

Can someone please point me to the code needed to implement multi-window in am app?

Also, can I dock the multi-window drawer on other sides of the screen, where a user may find then more convenient (at least being able to choose between a left-docking and a right-docking drawer.

Android KitKat 4.4.2.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK for supporting multi-window you only have to target SDK Level 24 and don't set any 'orientation' on your activities (because an app in multi window mode might have a landscape orientation even if the phone is in portrait mode and vice versa)

Comment: @ValentinKuhn Nope. Samsung have had it since Jellybean, maybe earlier.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question (since the rest are off topic, and the first one is your title question anyway) apps open in multi window can be shut by:

1. Tap anywhere in the app you want to shut.
2. Tap the Bar between the two windows (it may have an arrow pointing at that window you tapped, it may not)
3. Tap the X on the options that come up

**BUT BE WARNED!** If you opened an app over an app (for example, you opened YouTube, then gmail on top of it) it would switch to that app. Keep repeating the process to close any unneeded apps.

Comment: Sorry this solution is not working for me. Android 4.4.2 KitKat. I click on a window, then the blue dot that becomes a blue circle, and I can move it, but not close one of the windows. Thanks.

Comment: Please include a screenshot in your question. Trust me, it will help.

Comment: Done it, the app inn the top is Chrome, the one in the bottom its a music player. Was not able to capture the screen with the blue circle pressed (which enlarges when you press it, perhaps you can tell me how to do it). Thanks.

Comment: Done it. See if my question madness better sense now.

Comment: @JackMaddington Have you tried sliding the dot all the way up/down? Also, I note izzysoft in the top there :)

Comment: Yes, thanks. :-) However, when I slide the dot/ball all the way down, it disappears and the horizontal bar is reset to its original position.

Comment: How do I change this our configure a setting for it to work properly?

Comment: Also, I would like to take a screenshot while one of my fingers is on the screen (with the blue dot/ball pressed). I have tried the power-home key combination I normally use, but no luck. Can I use a different method, maybe a voice command?

Comment: @JackMaddington You could possibly screen-record, then take a screenshot of the recorded footage, but you may need root. What device do you have?

Comment: I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo, would love to be able to record video on my smartphone. Not sure how to do it. Could you please suggest how? Thanks.

Comment: @JackMaddington Just download an app like AZ screen recorder from the play store. Hmmm, I have am S3, and of shows the white bar I mentioned.